# Как в js поместить в переменную текст из textarea или input? Вопрос тривиальный, но

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
var word = document.getElementById("input").value;
btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);


function btnClick() {
    var p = document.getElementById("block");
    var node = p.cloneNode(true);
    console.log(word);
    console.log(node);
    node



    var tp = document.createTextNode(word);

}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="input">
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

Проблема - переменная word пустая, как говорит мне консоль, но текст я в `input` на сайте пишу. Что я делаю не так? Я менял в первой строке `.value` на `.innerText` - тот же результат, я менял `input` на `textarea` - тоже самое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что Вы пишете в переменную `word` значение поля когда оно пустое. Смотрите что там когда вызываете функцию обработчик и все получится.

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);

function btnClick() {
    var word = document.getElementById("input").value;
    console.log(word);

}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

Comment: ох, точно, мне стоило всего лишь логически подумать... Всё гениальное просто, как и решение этой проблемы))

Answer (score 0):

> Проблема - переменная word пустая, как говорит мне консоль, но текст я в input на сайте пишу. Что я делаю не так?

Использовать `id` плохая практика, которую нужно избегать.

Вот так например все работает:

```js
// Если нужно проверить свойства, то выбираем элемент
var word = document.querySelector(".input");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn")


btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);


function btnClick() {

  var p = document.querySelector(".block");
  var node = p.cloneNode(true);
  // Проверка атрибута value
  console.log(word.value);
  console.log(node);
  node

  var tp = document.createTextNode(word);

}
```

```html
<!-------- Не используйте id, лучше class -------->
<input class="input">
<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="btnClick" value="Click">
<p class="block">
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo.
</p>
```

---

**UPD:**

Уникальность (на странице) и вес `id`, делают его менее приемлемым для широкого применения на странице, в то время как `class` легче и может применятся многоразово. `class` предпочтительнее `id`.

[id против class](https://webo.in/articles/habrahabr/38-css-efficiency-tests-3/)

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/

Comment: _Использовать id плохая практика, которую нужно избегать._

Очень странная позиция, причин которой я не могу для себя найти, не могли бы вы объяснить свою точку зрения?

Comment: @VasiliyRusin Добавил.

Comment: На самом деле как раз уникальность на странице и делает id таким необходимым атрибутом. Если не учитывать оптимизации современных движков, то можно сказать что `getElementById` это самая быстра операция поиска по дереву DOM. А использование id для JS, а class для стилей это банально хороший тон web-разработчика. Даже если вы посмотрите на крупные framework'и вродe React/Angular/Vue не смотря на то что явно они не используют id, классы в них используются исключительно для стилей, а связка с теневым DOM, происходит по уникальным не повторяющимся идентификаторам, ничего не напоминает?